# Call a component of vue 3 inside another component but in the part of <script setup>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `vue3` component and I don't want to use it in the template of another component but in the script setup.

```
<script setup>

import A from '../components/component.vue'

import { h, ref} from 'vue'

$('#container').h(<component>)

</script>

<template>
    <div class="app-content content ">
        <div class="content-overlay"></div>
        <div class="content-wrapper container-xxl p-0">
            <div class="content-header row"></div>
            <div class="content-body">
                <div id="container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you add a more detailed description, why you want to do it like this? I feel like this approach is somehow not really nice and I guess there might be a much cleaner approach to your problem.

Comment: Did you check the [slot api](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html)? It might fit your need. I think, you need to think differently.